# Can't initialize a vector with a variable int

Tags: c++, string, vector, integer, constants

I was under the impression that vector could be created using a variable integer. I got this impression from the second answer here: [How to create an array when the size is a variable not a constant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459248/how-to-create-an-array-when-the-size-is-a-variable-not-a-constant)

However I still get the "constant int" error message for the code below:

```
#include <vector>
size_t ports_specified = std::count(Ports.begin(), Ports.end(), '+');
const int num_ports = static_cast<int>(ports_specified++);
std::vector<string> port_info[num_ports];
```

Comment: You're creating an array of vectors.

Comment: You're creating an array of `std::vector`. You might want `std::vector<string> port_info(num_ports); //initialize vector with num_ports elements`.

Comment: "Initialize"? C++ supports several forms/syntaxes of initiazliation, but none of them includes `[]` as a syntactic element. I.e. your `[num_ports]` cannot possibly be an initializer. Which means that it is interpreted by the compiler as something completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details matter.

```
std::vector<string> port_info[num_ports];
```

This is declaring a static array of `num_ports` number of `std::vector<string>` elements.  A static array needs a compile-time constant, not a runtime constant, thus the error.

```
std::vector<string> port_info(num_ports);
```

This is declaring a single `std::vector<string>` that is constructed with `num_ports` as an input value.

In other words, use parenthesis instead of brackets.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to create an array of n `vector<string>`;
not a `vector<string>` of n elements.

To do the latter in **C++11**, vector supports a constructor that takes a `size_type`.

```
explicit vector( size_type count );
```

In **C++14**, it was changed to have a default Allocator.

```
explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

You can const a vector of 10 integers like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){

  std::vector<int> v(10);
  std::cout << v.size() << '\n';

  for (auto it: v){
    std::cout << it << " "; //prints: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   }
 }
```

The vector uses [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization), so you guaranteed integer values of zero.

You can also set an initial value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){

  std::vector<int> v(10,7);
  std::cout << v.size() << '\n';

 for (auto it: v){
    std::cout << it << " "; //prints: 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7
  }
}
```