# User define array size

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I found a difficulty on creating an array with user defined size. It shows error, can anybody teach me how to do this?

```
int main()
{
    int row, column;
    cout << "Enter the amount of row" << endl;
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Enter the amount of column" << endl;
    cin >> column;
    int array[row][column]; //the value of variable cannot be used as a constant
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You can do that in C, but not in C++. Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Older duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459248/how-to-create-an-array-when-the-size-is-a-variable-not-a-constant), but the accepted answer is not recommended in modern C++ code.

Comment: Dynamically allocate the array.  Hint:  use `operator new`.

Comment: May you show me how to achieve it?